# Do MVC get and post action methods share parameter values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and was wondering why/how the following occurs. I have two action methods in my controller for method TEST, one for Get and the other for Post. Each contain a "sortby" parameter. When I call the Get method, "sortby" is set to "ABC". When the submit button is clicked and the Post method is called, the "sortby" parameter for the Post method has the value of "ABC". My question is why? No hidden field values, model does not contain "sortby" field.

```
    public ActionResult Test(string sortby = "")
    {
        return View(myModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(modelType myModel, string sortby = "")
    {
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to sortby on a post?  The convention for posts are that they should be used to alter data.

Comment: Please disregard the name of the parameter. I would simply like to know the logistics behind the fact that this parameter maintains is value from the "get" to the "post" without saving the value in the model or in a hidden field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling your POST after the GET which is returning the view with myModel data (and likely the sortby params defined)?  More information is needed to tell you why this is happening, I'm just guessing, but they shouldn't be sharing anything.  Somehow you are telling both methods to use those params.

Comment: The post is called when the submit button on the view is clicked.  Sortby information is not saved in the view.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Actually if you are requesting a GET with a param and then POSTing without removing the param, the param will be sent along the POST as a default, you'll want to tell your POST action to use its own param in the HTML form tag, otherwise its defaulting to the URL you already sent as the GET

Comment: Thank you Lazy Coder, you nailed it. I looked at my FORM tag and saw that the params for the Get were being used as the params for the Post. This is why I could see the parameter values in both methods. I am new to MVC and appreciate your time and great insight.

Answer (score 3):

*Nothing* is shared between requests to different actions. The only thing that exists is what was included in the request (query string for a GET, post body for a POST, and the URL itself).

You haven't given any information about how your URLs are set up, but assuming that you had a route like `/test/{sortby}`, when you postback to that URL, the `sortby` param would be filled from the URL, just as it would be with a GET. Otherwise, it *must* be included in the post body for it to be populated, meaning you do have a hidden field somewhere in your form holding that value.

Comment: To expand, it you do have a route with `.../Test/{sortby}`, then the value of `sortby` is being added as a route parameter (look at the html of the form element your generating - it will have `/Test/ABC`),